# JQuery AJAX returns OK 200 , but no response

Tags: jquery

I have a website where I am using JQuery to make an AJAX call to a PHP page.  The PHP page takes the parameters passed from the AJAX call and inserts the data into a MySQL database.

When I call the API directly by inserting the URL string into my URL bar, everything works and I get a response.  However, my firebug console doesn't show a response.  I see changes reflected in the database, so I know that the parameters are being passed and the PHP/MySQL is ok. In firebug, the console shows '200 ok' for the query string, but the query string is red instead of the usual black.

The file that contains the PHP code is on the same server as the page that is calling it.  The site is hosted on a GoDaddy shared webhosting legacy grid.

I'm at a loss for what's going on.  It's important that I figure this out, as I have JQuery code that depends on getting a response from the API.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Didn't you [just ask this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506936/please-help-me-troubleshoot-api-jquery-issue-with-website)?

Comment: No, but I did ask a similar one.  I am trying to work through possible problems.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the PHP file is actually writing data to the return stream?

Check to make sure your are calling `echo $response;` where $response is the data you want to return.

Comment: Yes, I've confirmed that data is being returned.  When I call the API directly by entering the URL with parameters into my browser URL bar, I get the response.  Plus the exact same code works fine on my localhost server.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: could you provide a snippet of the firebug output for the failed AJAX call?